# Javascript Application with ASP.NET/jQuery, Best Practice

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to create a Javascript Application like GMail with:

> Framework: ASP.NET
>
> Browser Framework: jQuery
>
> Database: MySQL

My idea is:

When the window.onhashchange fires up, i load the right content dynamically:

```
main.loadContent = function (file) {
   $("#content").load(file); } // in this example, users.aspx
```

the javascript file "users.js" gets loaded too and on dom ready, i get some informations from the server via ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService.asmx/GetUsers",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        // fill the fields
    }
});
```

the function GetUsers in the webservice, fires up and returns data from the database:

```
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetUsers()
    {
        try
        {
           return Users.GetUsers(); //some logic and database query
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Global.HandleException(ex); }
    }
}
```

So, is this a good one or do you have a better one?

Comment: this doesn't correspond any problem, its more of a code review related. You will get better answers at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ASP.NET MVC because mixing jQuery Ajax with ASP.NET postbacks/viewstates etc can be quite painfull.

ASP.NET MVC will ease the client side (javascript) development by giving you complete control on the html.